# How to access the rest of a 500 GB hard drive that ubuntu is installed on?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, on a second Hard drive (500 GB), but only 50 GB appears accessible to me. How do I access the remainder of 450 GB?

On the 1st Hard drive, windows 7 shows the other 2 partitions (450 GB), of the 2nd drive in the 'disk manager', that I don't seem to be able to access.

Comment: Could you run `gparted` and show the result for the disk ? Or, from a terminal, `parted -l`

Comment: I agree with Soren, perhaps there is an un allocated/un formatted partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the rest of the 450 GB is in the `/temp` directory, that was not shown in the left-hand source directories of the folders tab.

My hard disk has now been resized using `gparted` so that the Ubuntu partition has ~200 GB. This achieved by booting to a USB stick with Ubuntu 16.04 on it, as the hard drive could not be re-partitioned whilst I was using it.

Comment: That is unclear. Both Q & A.

Comment: Having 50G Ubuntu partition and a 450 G temp partition seems....suboptimal.

Comment: Sounds bad. You know that Linux can clear whatever is in /temp dir at any time, right?

Comment: I think you mean the `/tmp` directory is usually emptied daily not `temp` which is a MS-DOS era convention.